# Store returned Twitter JSON geolocation as variable

Tags: php, mysql, json, twitter, geolocation

I'm using PHP to submit a JSON query to Twitter's API (using POST method), and am including geolocation coordinates as one of the criteria in order to get geolocation data back. From the returned JSON results, I'm storing specific values as variables to pas to MySQL (first converting to strings). I've been successful in getting the JSON results and can see latitude/longitude data in my browser, but haven't been able to successfully grab/store them. The below code works for grabbing all other fields (text, created_at, etc). Any help would be appreciated.

This is the portion of the code where I'm decoding the JSON results/assigning a variable for each field/sending the variable to MySQL.

```
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($tweet->{'status'}->{'geo'});
```

Comment: As stated in [the introduction to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php): *This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.*

Comment: what does it say when you `var_dump($tweet->{'status'}->{'geo'})` and `var_dump($data)`

Comment: Vatev, getting 'Undefined Class' and 'NULL' - so I'm assuming I'm not pointing to the coordinates correctly. How would I set up the line above? IE I want to pull in the "coordinates" values from the following results:
https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?locations=-180,-90,180,90

Comment: I'm not familiar with twitter's response datastructures, have you tried dump-ing the entire $tweet.

Comment: Never really gave that a thought - as a last resort I guess I could just throw the whole tweet as a field into MySQL and sort out the different structures from there. Thanks..

Comment: By dumping it I meant debugging (var_dump,print_r,...) the entire thing to see if the fields are there at all or if they have some other names.

Comment: oh - the fields are there given I see the raw JSON results in a browser (via link I used above) - the issue is getting to those specific fields. I've tried $tweet->geo->children('georss', true)->point, to no avail, and was hoping someone knew the twitter structure well enough to assist.

Answer (score 0):

The [Twitter API doco](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets) notes that the `geo` field is being deprecated, so you want to look at the `coordinates` field from now.

This field is optional, so it is possible it is null. However since you are filtering on location this should be unlikely. If it is present, you should get something like this:

```php
var_dump($tweet->coordinates);

// Output:
object(stdClass)[5]
  public 'type' => string 'Point' (length=5)
  public 'coordinates' => 
    array
      0 => float -99.98741865
      1 => float 21.9250252
```

If not you'll just get `null`. To get the lat/long of the tweet, you should be able to do:

```
if ($tweet->coordinates != null) {
    $long = $tweet->coordinates->coordinates[0];
    $lat = $tweet->coordinates->coordinates[1];
}
```